# Manipulate attributes before angular 4 compiles it

Tags: angular

I am rewriting a library (which was developed by me in angular1.x) using angular4. 
In that library I used to copy the attributes from wrapper directive to inner html element.
For Example `<gn-input component.ng-model="somevar"></gn-input>`

Html Template for `gn-Input` directive has `<input class="component" type="text" />`

In compile function of gn-input, I used to read all attributes on the gn-input element and copy them on input.component (with component class) tag. This was giving me flexibility because I was using inherited scope (scope:true)

---- To make it more clear
For example, there is one more directive, I developed

```
<gn-address country.ng-model="countryField" state.ng-model="stateField"></gn-address>
```

In template of gn-address, there were two inputs (actually dropdowns but assume inputs for simplicity) `<input class='country' type="text" /> and 
    <input class='state' type="text" />`.

In compile function of gn-address I used to read all attributes on the element of gn-address and setAttribute them on respective inputs of class.

This approach saved lots of my efforts to support all the directives which inner elements do support and wrapper was actually a wrapper.

I am so much used to angular1 and it's flexibility, I am finding it difficult to do the same thing in angular4 keeping the library AOT compatible.